# Display swipable image slider and swipable tabs on single activity

Tags: android

I want to create single activity having swipable image slider and swipable tabs. But i dont have an idea how to create this. I tried ViewPager is used for full screen swipe to get next full screen. Can any body tell me how to do that.

See image which demonstrates my need. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Single acivity with swipable image slider and swipable tabs]

Comment: you can simply use two viewpagers and a tab view @Adnan

Comment: view pager occupies full screen so how it ts possible to display 2 viewpagers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly, but I think there is an official Android sample that does exactly that:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SlidingTabsColors/

This is at least a reasonable starting point..